# Anti group by/R apply in Pyspark

Tags: r, group-by, sapply, pyspark

I am R programmer moving into the pyspark world and have gotten a lot of the basic tricks down but something I am still struggling about is things I would do applys or basic for loops for.

In this case I am trying to calculate the "anti-groupby" for an ID. Basically the idea is to look at a population for that ID and then the population for not this ID and have both those values on the same row. The getting the population for that ID is easy using a groupby and then joining it to a dataset with new_id as the only column.

This is how I would do it in R:

```
anti_group <- function(id){
    tr <- sum(subset(df1, new_id!=id)$total_1)
    to <- sum(subset(df1, new_id!=id)$total_2)
    54 * tr / to
  }
  test$other.RP54 <- sapply(test$new_id, anti_group  )
```

How would I do it in pyspark?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
#df.show()
#sample data
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   40|
|  1|   30|
|  2|   10|
|  2|   90|
|  3|   20|
|  3|   10|
|  4|    2|
|  4|    5|
+---+-----+
```

Then some function that creates a final dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---+-------------+------------------+
| id|grouped_total|anti_grouped_total|
+---+-------------+------------------+
|  1|           70|               137|
|  2|          100|               107|
|  3|           30|               177|
|  4|            7|               200|
+---+-------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no in-built function that would replicate that groupBy function, but you could easily do it by creating a new column using  **`case(when/otherwise clause)`** to create your *group and anti-group*, and then **`groupBy`** on that **`new column`**.

```
#df.show()
#sample data
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   40|
|  1|   30|
|  2|   10|
|  2|   90|
|  3|   20|
|  3|   10|
|  4|    2|
|  4|    5|
+---+-----+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("anti_id_1", F.when(F.col("id")==1, F.lit('1')).otherwise(F.lit('Not_1')))\
  .groupBy("anti_id_1").agg(F.sum("value").alias("sum")).show()

+---------+---+
|anti_id_1|sum|
+---------+---+
|        1| 70|
|    Not_1|137|
+---------+---+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w1=Window().partitionBy("id")
w=Window().partitionBy()
df.withColumn("grouped_total",F.sum("value").over(w1))\
  .withColumn("anti_grouped_total", (F.sum("value").over(w))-F.col("grouped_total"))\
  .groupBy("id").agg(F.first("grouped_total").alias("grouped_total"),\
                     F.first("anti_grouped_total").alias("anti_grouped_total"))\
  .drop("value").orderBy("id").show()


+---+-------------+------------------+
| id|grouped_total|anti_grouped_total|
+---+-------------+------------------+
|  1|           70|               137|
|  2|          100|               107|
|  3|           30|               177|
|  4|            7|               200|
+---+-------------+------------------+
```

**`Less verbose/concise`** way to achieve the same output:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy()
df.groupBy("id").agg(F.sum("value").alias("grouped_total"))\
          .withColumn("anti_grouped_total",F.sum("grouped_total").over(w)-F.col("grouped_total")).orderBy("id"),show()
```

**`For 2 value columns:`**

```
df.show()
+---+------+------+
| id|value1|value2|
+---+------+------+
|  1|    40|    50|
|  1|    30|    70|
|  2|    10|    91|
|  2|    90|    21|
|  3|    20|    42|
|  3|    10|     4|
|  4|     2|    23|
|  4|     5|    12|
+---+------+------+

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window().partitionBy()
df.groupBy("id").agg(F.sum("value1").alias("grouped_total_1"),F.sum("value2").alias("grouped_total_2"))\
          .withColumn("anti_grouped_total_1",F.sum("grouped_total_1").over(w)-F.col("grouped_total_1"))\
          .withColumn("anti_grouped_total_2",F.sum("grouped_total_2").over(w)-F.col("grouped_total_2")).orderBy("id").show()

+---+---------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|grouped_total_1|grouped_total_2|anti_grouped_total_1|anti_grouped_total_2|
+---+---------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|             70|            120|                 137|                 193|
|  2|            100|            112|                 107|                 201|
|  3|             30|             46|                 177|                 267|
|  4|              7|             35|                 200|                 278|
+---+---------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I added some more info to be clearer (sorry!) using your sample data, thank you for your help. Yours works if we have 4 IDs and I could manually iterate but if I have 1000+ values it won't sadly.

Comment: Quick question, what if I was wanting to create two grouped and two anti grouped columns? Like there was a value 1 and a value 2, and wanted grouped value 1, anti grouped value 1, grouped value 2 and anti grouped value 2?

Comment: u would have add another sum in the agg of the groupby, and add another withcolumn to compute the difference using the window. check my update for 2 value columns.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that in two steps: first you sum by id then you take the total and substract by the value for this id.

My idea is a little bit like a `group_by(id) %>% summarise(x = sum(x)) %>% mutate(y  = sum(x) - x)` in `dplyr`

The solution I propose is based on `Window` function. It is untested:

Let's first create the data

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import pyspark.sql.window as psw

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,40),(1,30),(2,10),(2,90),(3,20),(3,10),(4,2),(4,5)], ['id','value'])

df.show(2)

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   40|
|  1|   30|
+---+-----+
only showing top 2 rows
```

and then apply that approach:

```py
w = psw.Window.orderBy()
df_id = df.groupBy("id").agg(psf.sum("value").alias("grouped_total"))
df_id = (df_id
          .withColumn("anti_grouped_total",psf.sum("grouped_total").over(w))
          .withColumn('anti_grouped_total', psf.col('anti_grouped_total') - psf.col('grouped_total'))
        )

df_id.show(2)
+---+-------------+------------------+
| id|grouped_total|anti_grouped_total|
+---+-------------+------------------+
|  3|           30|               177|
|  1|           70|               137|
+---+-------------+------------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

Comment: Interesting, that is definitely one way to do it. Just do a group by and then append the full population sums to the dataframe and do the difference which is easy. I added some sample data and sample output to an edit to be a little more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You guys basically had the same answer, he was basically just first. Thank you for the R similarity.

Comment: @BaseballR  u can give him the accepted answer, idc. im just here to help and learn. cheers!